# Android sonar fails with "Please check that inclusion/exclusion patterns produce disjoint sets for main and test files"

Tags: android, sonarqube

I keep running into this issue with sonarqube recently:

```
Caused by: File common/something/build.gradle.kts can't be indexed twice. Please check that inclusion/exclusion patterns produce disjoint sets for main and test files
```

My sonar setup:

```kotlin
configure<SonarExtension> {
    properties {
        property("sonar.log.level", "VERBOSE")
        property("sonar.exclusions", listOf("INSERT EXCLUSIONS HERE"))
        property("sonar.coverage.exclusions", listOf("INSERT SOME EXCLUSION HERE"))
        property("sonar.test.exclusions", listOf("**/**/*"))
        property("sonar.java.coveragePlugin", "jacoco")
        property("sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths", "$rootDir/build/reports/jacoco/jacocoUnitTestReport/jacocoUnitTestReport.xml")
        androidVariant = "debug"
    }
}
```

I looked through similar issues on stack overflow and most point to some intersection between `sonar.tests` and `sonar.sources`. I tried removing `sonar.test.exclusions` and adding it to `sonar.coverage.exclusions` but still didn't work. I also tried removing both `sonar.coverage.exclusions` and `sonar.test.exclusions` and adding them to `sonar.exclusions` but that didn't help either

Sonarqube version: `4.3.0.3225`
plugin: `org.sonarqube`